# How to remove special controller from navigationController's viewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to write a `class` method with two `params` to delete `viewController` from `navigation controller`, but I don't know how to do with it.

My code is below, I tested, not success:

```
class func removeVC(_ fromNav:UINavigationController, _ controller:UIViewController) {

    let controllers:NSArray = fromNav.viewControllers as NSArray
    for item in controllers {

        if (item as AnyObject).isMember(of:controller) { // There is not pass by Xcode

             // remove item out of fromNav.viewControllers
        }
    }
}
```

How to judge the `controller`'s `class` equals to the param `controller` in `swift`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

Method 1)

```
class func removeVC(fromNav: UINavigationController, controller: UIViewController) {

    let controllers = fromNav.viewControllers
    for item in controllers {

        if item == controller {
            fromNav.viewControllers.remove(at: fromNav.viewControllers.index(of: item)!)
        }

    }
}
```

Usage: `UtilSwift.navRemoveVC(self.navigationController!, self)`

Method 2):

```
class func navRemoveVC(_ fromNav:UINavigationController, withControllerClass:AnyClass) {

    let controllers = fromNav.viewControllers
    for item in controllers {
        if (item as AnyObject).isKind(of: withControllerClass.self) {
            fromNav.viewControllers.remove(at: fromNav.viewControllers.index(of: item)!)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage: `UtilSwift.navRemoveVC(self.navigationController!, withControllerClass:UserRegisterViewController.self)`

Comment: Your answer is right, BTW, if I get a `controller` name `String`: such as `ViewController2`,  how can I get the index of the `navigation controller`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
   if (item as AnyObject).isKind(of: UIViewController.self){
        // remove item out of fromNav.viewControllers
   }
```